# How is jquery actually used after importing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing my very first project from scratch, previously I have used bootstrap templates and changed a lot in them, but I always ran into issues with classes and it got really complicated, so I'm trying with just the bootstrap css and js, and jquery because it seemed all the templates I was using had jquery imported.

But as I've gotten more familiar with javascript I've been making specific .js files for things like smooth scrolling with easing and opacity fades. But in all the templates I used those things seemed to just work and there was only a jquery cdn and jquery easing, how do I actually go about applying what is in jquery (and what is actually in it?) to my classes or implement the smooth scrolling and validation features?

For example for smooth scrolling I had to make my own (got it from here actually) bit of js and target the navbar and edit some variables myself.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar
  $(".navbar a.scroll,.navbar a.navbar-brand").on('click', function(event) {

  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - $('.navbar').height()
  }, 1600, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
})
```

Do I need to do this in the jquery js file as well or?

Thanks

Comment: "Do I need to do this in the jquery js file as well" Nah you're good

Comment: no I mean do I need to change variables so jquery takes effect?

Comment: sounds like you need this: http://learn.jquery.com/